# Single Link List in Python Add, Remove, Insert

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list

I'm trying to achieve a singly linked list with add, remove and insert methods. I'm confused with the insertion method.

```
class Node(object):

def __init__(self, data, next):
    self.data = data
    self.next = next

class SingleList(object):

head = None
tail = None

def printList(self):
    print "Link List:"
    current_node = self.head
    while current_node is not None:
        print current_node.data, " --> ",
        current_node = current_node.next
    print None

def add(self, data):
    node = Node(data, None)
    if self.head is None:
        self.head = self.tail = node
    else:
        self.tail.next = node
    self.tail = node

def insert(self, before, nextdata):
    #nextdata is to be inserted before 'before'
    #before is actually a data 
    #but it has dif name in this def to avoid confusion with 'data'
    current_node = self.head
    previous_node = None
    while current_node is not None:
        if current_node.data == before:
            if previous_node is not None:
                current_node.next = current_node
        previous_node = current_node
        current_node = current_node.next

def remove(self, node_value):
    current_node = self.head
    previous_node = None
    while current_node is not None:
        if current_node.data == node_value:
            # if this is the first node (head)
            if previous_node is not None:
                previous_node.next = current_node.next
            else:
                self.head = current_node.next
        # needed for the next iteration
        previous_node = current_node
        current_node = current_node.next
```

Link List:

```
1  -->  2  -->  3  -->  4  -->  5  -->  None
```

Link List:

```
3  -->  4  -->  6  -->  10  -->  None
```

For example if I'm trying to do insert (4,9) which inserts number 9 before 4.

```
s = SingleList()
s.add(1)
s.add(2)
s.add(3)
s.add(4)
s.add(5)
s.printList()
s.add(6)
s.add(10)
s.remove(5)
s.remove(2)
s.remove(1)
s.printList()
s.insert(4,9)
s.printList()
```

Any help will do, snippets, advice anything not spoon feeding. Thanks!

Comment: Your insert method is going to insert that number before every occurrence of the other number in the list. I assume you don't want that?

Comment: `current_node.next = current_node` Now the node points to itself.

Comment: Where are you using `nextdata` in that method?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You have to rewrite your insert as:

```
def insert(self, before, nextdata):
    #nextdata is to be inserted before 'before'
    #before is actually a data
    #but it has dif name in this def to avoid confusion with 'data'
    current_node = self.head
    previous_node = None
    while current_node is not None:
        if current_node.data == before:
            if previous_node is not None:
                temp_node = current_node
                current_node = Node(nextdata, temp_node)
                previous_node.next = current_node
            else:
                new_node = Node(nextdata, current_node)
                self.head = new_node
            break
        previous_node = current_node
        current_node = current_node.next
```

This will take care of it. When you insert the new node you have to break your loop otherwise it will be infinite.

Comment: `if current_node.data == before:`
Can it be Node instead of using data?

Comment: Thanks for this but is there a way to insert a node without using data?